# future_post hook isn't working for scheduled posts notification

Tags: wordpress, post, scheduled-tasks, hook, android-notifications

I want to sent notification while scheduling the post in wordpress. In have tried below functions. But nothing is not triggered.

add_action('future_to_publish','on_post_scheduled');

add_action('publish_post','on_post_scheduled',10,2 );

add_action('future_post','on_post_scheduled', 10, 2 );

add_action('publish_future_post', 'on_post_scheduled');

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173321/any-way-to-create-scheduled-post-programatically 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-posts these links might help you.

Comment: I have tried this `function on_post_scheduled($ID) {//Code for notification } add_action('publish_future_post', 'on_post_scheduled'); ` Its working fine.